# How to inject dynamic id for body of pact contract written in Java?

Tags: java, pact

We have a put api that will update an assignment based on its id. As we should be cleaning up the data after a test, our assignment id would change after the original one is deleted, so we're trying to dynamically inject that into the body for the request from the provider side. However, we seem to be perhaps missing something here as it's not updating correctly and the request is still being triggered with the id set as the example.

This is the provider class:

```
@Slf4j
@Provider("Assignments API")
@Consumer("LTI-AGS-Tool")
//@PactBroker(url = BROKER_PACT_URL, authentication = @PactBrokerAuth(token = "${pactbroker.auth.token}"))
@VerificationReports(value = {"console", "markdown"}, reportDir = "target/pacts")
class PactProviderLTIAGSIT {

    private HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    private String updateAssignmentId;
    private final String SERVICE_TOKEN = "myToken";

    @BeforeEach
    void createTeacherAssignment() {

        String assignmentBody = createBodyStringForStudentAssignmentSetup();

        assignmentBody = assignmentBody.replace("CPWAG", "OTHER_TEXT_RESOURCE");

        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("Authorization", "myToken");

        RequestSpecification rq = Util.getRequestSpecification().baseUri(baseAssignmentUrl).headers(headers);
        Response response = rq.body(assignmentBody).post();
        assertEquals(201, response.getStatusCode());

        updateAssignmentId = response.jsonPath().get("assignments[0].refId");

        log.info("assignment id is " + updateAssignmentId);
    }

    @TestTemplate
    @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
    void pactTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context, HttpRequest request) {

        request.addHeader("Authorization", SERVICE_TOKEN);
        logCurlFromPact(context, request);
        context.verifyInteraction();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void before(PactVerificationContext context) {
        context.setTarget(new HttpsTestTarget(BASE_PACT_TEACHER_ASSIGNMENTS_URL, 443, ""));
    }

    @State("Scoring info is passed between ags-tool and assignmentapi")
    Map<String, Object> getScoringInfo() {

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("assignmentId", updateAssignmentId);
        return map;
    }
}
```

And here the consumer contract:

```
@ExtendWith(PactConsumerTestExt.class)
class PactConsumerSendScoreIT {

    private final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    private final String path = "/v5/assignmentStatus/update";

    @Pact(provider = PACT_PROVIDER, consumer = PACT_CONSUMER)
    public RequestResponsePact scoreConsumerPact(PactDslWithProvider builder) {

        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

        //Body given and returned
        DslPart body = new PactDslJsonBody()
                .valueFromProviderState("assignmentId", "assignmentId", "c1ef3bbf-55a2-4638-8f93-22b2916fe085")
                .stringType("timestamp", DateTime.now().plusHours(3).toString())
                .decimalType("scoreGiven", 75.00)
                .decimalType("scoreMaximum", 100.00)
                .stringType("comment", "Good work!")
                .stringType("status", "IN_PROGRESS")
                .stringType("userId", "c2ef3bbf-55a2-4638-8f93-22b2916fe085")
                .close();

        return builder
                .given("Scoring info is passed between ags-tool and assignmentapi")
                .uponReceiving("Scoring info is passed between ags-tool and assignmentapi")
                .path(path)
                .method("POST")
                .body(body)
                .headers(headers)
                .willRespondWith()
                .status(201)
                .body(body)
                .toPact();

    }

    @Test
    @PactTestFor(pactMethod = "scoreConsumerPact", providerName = PACT_PROVIDER, port = "8080", pactVersion = PactSpecVersion.V3)
    void runTest(MockServer mockServer) {

        String updateAssignmentId = "c2ef3bbf-55a2-4638-8f93-22b2916fe085";

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("timestamp", DateTime.now().plusHours(3).toString());
        map.put("scoreGiven", 75.00);
        map.put("scoreMaximum", 100.00);
        map.put("comment", "Good work!");
        map.put("status", "IN_PROGRESS");
        map.put("userId", "c2ef3bbf-55a2-4638-8f93-22b2916fe085");
        map.put("assignmentId", updateAssignmentId);

        //Mock url
        RequestSpecification rq = Util.getRequestSpecification().baseUri(mockServer.getUrl()).headers(headers);

        Response response = rq.body(map)
                .post(path);

        assertEquals(201, response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out that the expression needed is to include the ${} (at least if it's a string).
Once we updated it to valueFromProviderState("assignmentId", "${assignmentId}", "c1ef3bbf-55a2-4638-8f93-22b2916fe085") it seemed to work.